# Method does not override method from its super class & cannot resolve symbol

Tags: java, android, overriding

In Override, I get a "Method does not override method from its super class" error. I also get "onResume cannot resolve method" error in super.onResume ();

It was working on MainActivity but when I move the code to Service class, I got this error.

[As you can see:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Raub9.png)

```
public class Servis extends Service implements SensorEventListener{

    SensorManager mgr;
    Sensor temp;
    TextView text;
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder(2048);
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Servis.this, R.raw.warning);
        mgr = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        temp = mgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE); }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        mgr.registerListener(this, temp, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mgr.unregisterListener(this, temp);
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            float fahrenheit = event.values[0] * 9 / 5 + 32;
            if(fahrenheit < 68)
                mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: The MainActivity class inherits from Activity (or AppCompatActivity), which has an onResume method to override. Here, it seems that you are extending from Service, which has no onResume method: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: @tlong314 `SensorEventListener` is not a `Service`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) is not an [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity), that's why these methods cannot be overridden. You can safely remove them and instead have to let the `Activity` implement them. When a `Service implements SensorEventListener`, this would look alike this:

```
public class Servis extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }    
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, Services class does not include the methods you so there is no override to be performed.  Refer to [Service documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

The closes method you might want to consider it to override

```
onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
```

It's perhaps the closest to OnResume